# Bug using PHP SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have my application in which I store a `$_SESSION['userId']` variable to know if the user is logged in, and what user it is. Here is my piece of code in the index:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']) || empty($_SESSION['userId']) )
{
  header("Location: login.php");
}
```

and the code in the login is the other way around.

Everything worked fine until now, I am having a little bug. I modified the code above into this:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']) || empty($_SESSION['userId']) )
{
  header("Location: login.php");
}else{
  echo "<script>console.log('user id is set');</script>";
}
```

If I run it this way, the console log appears correctly. But if I change the `console.log` line to this: `echo "<script>console.log('user id=".$_SESSION['userId']."');</script>";` then the site never loads, and no error appears in console.

Any idea of what could be happening? Just to let you know, I found this bug in a `.php` file which inserts content into a sql database using the `userId SESSION variable`, and suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: never loads? as in white page of death? turn on error_reporting and display_errors.

Comment: try adding an `exit;` after your header.

Comment: To expand @MarcB's comment, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to your script to display any errors that are occurring.

Comment: view source in browser. Does the userid by any chance contain quotes in it?

Comment: I reloaded everything and now it works. I think what may have happened is that my session variable has expired and that was causing the problem. Does anyone know if the session variable is expired the `isset` should returns true? Is there any way to check if the variable is expired?

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting and/or display_error are probably set to display nothing (production environnement). Try setting them on to see the actual error.

You should escape the quotes of `$_SESSION['userId']` with `addslashes()` or equivalents.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']) || empty($_SESSION['userId']) )
{
  header("Location: login.php");
}else{
  echo "<script>console.log('user id=".addslashes($_SESSION['userId'])."');</script>";
}
```

If this doesn't work, the problem is certainly in another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, this is not a good idea to use javascript in this context.
The javascript console is not design for php debug
Why don't you just display the sucess login message `echo $_SESSION['userId'];` ?